# Does the following limit exist (using Riesz representation theorem)

Tags: analysis

[image: Real Analysis by Carothers]

Having trouble understanding how to start this question. Do we find alpha? Then what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will state a some idea for the solution : Note that $\alpha_n$ has a bounded variation so that we have $$
F_n(f):= \int_0^1 f(x)d\alpha_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=2}^n
f(\log_n k) $$

Note that $$ \alpha_n\rightarrow \alpha,\ \alpha(x)=0\ (0\leq x<
1),\ \alpha (1)=1$$

So $$ F(f)=\int_0^1 f d\alpha =f(1) $$